# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n\frac{f(\frac{x}{n})}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

In the middle of an exercise I have to compute:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n\frac{f(\frac{x}{n})}{1+x^2}dx$$

($f\in C[0,1]$) It is obvious that this has to be equal to:
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(0)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}f(0)$$

But I am not sure how to prove it in a rigurous way, since you can have divergence problems or some weird situations.

Comment: How about using ε-δ? I turned off my computer a minute ago, so I can give you only a hint like this

Comment: @Nightflight Yes, of course, this has to be the the way to prove it, but having an integral and an arbitary function makes it really hard for me to do it.

Comment: Do we know anything more about $f$? for instance, is it decreasing or bounded maybe? If so we could perhaps use one of  Lebesgue's convergence theorems.

Comment: You need some restriction on $f(u)$ in addition to continuity.  $f(1)=\infty$ may be a problem.

Comment: @fwd nope, only that it is continuous on $[0,1]$, but maybe we can use dominated convergence theorem, since $f$ is bounded in $[0,1]$. Another idea I was thinking was that maybe its easier to prove that it is a cauchy sequence, and since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, the serie is convergent , what do you think?

Comment: @herbsteinberg yeah sorry, it is continuous in the compact $[0,1]$, I'll edit the post.

Comment: I'd suggest  to start with a change of variables: $z= \frac{x}{n}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $|f(x)|\le B$ on $[0,1]$, and given $\epsilon>0$, we can choose $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ for $x\in [0, \delta]$. Now $$|\int_0^n \frac{f(x/n)-f(0)}{1+x^2}dx| \le \int_0^{\delta n} |\frac{f(x/n)-f(0)}{1+x^2}| + \int_{\delta n}^\infty \frac{2B}{1+x^2}$$ $$\le \int_0^{\delta n} \frac{\epsilon}{1+x^2} + \int_{\delta n}^\infty\frac{2B}{1+x^2}\le \epsilon\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\int_{\delta n}^\infty \frac{2B}{1+x^2}$$

Because $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx<\infty$, for sufficiently large $n$, $\int_{\delta n}^\infty \frac{2B}{1+x^2}dx\le \epsilon$, hence finally

$$|\int_0^n \frac{f(x/n)-f(0)}{1+x^2}dx|\le (\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^2}+1)\epsilon$$

More generally, this can be used to show that $$\int_0^n f(x/n)g(x)dx\rightarrow f(0)\int_0^\infty g(x)dx$$ if $f$ is bounded on $[0, 1]$ and right continuous at $0$, and $\int_0^\infty |g(x)|dx<\infty$.

Comment: Why you can assume $\delta_n$ is increasing?

Comment: $\delta$ doesn't depend on $n$, but only on $\epsilon$. (To be clear, I mean $\delta\cdot n$, not $\delta_n$ is the answer.)

Comment: Right, then all good, it was just a confusion on the notation.

Comment: @Justauser: In the very first inequality, did you use $\int_0^{n} \le \int_0^{\infty}$ because the integrand function is nonnegative and then splitted $\int_0^{\infty}=\int_0^{\delta n}+\int_{\delta n}^{\infty}$? And have you chosen $\delta n$ as point to split the interval to be sure that then $\frac{x}{n} \in [0,\delta]$ and so you can use the estimation from the continuity? Thanks.

Comment: Yes to both of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n\frac{f(\frac{x}{n})}{1+x^2}dx
$

This looks like
the usual
split the integral
and see what happens,
so I'll do that.

For $0 < c < n$,
let
$I_n
=\int_0^n\frac{f(\frac{x}{n})}{1+x^2}dx
$,
$J_n(c)
=\int_0^{c}\frac{f(\frac{x}{n})}{1+x^2}dx
$,
$K_n(c)
=\int_c^n\frac{f(\frac{x}{n})}{1+x^2}dx
$,
so
$I_n
=J_n(c)+K_n(c)
$.

I want
$K_n(c)
$
to be small
and
$J_n(c)$
to be close to
$\int_0^{c}\frac{f(0)}{1+x^2}dx
$
so we can let
$c\to\infty$
and get your result.

Looking at
$J_n(c)$,
we want to make
$c/n \to 0$.

Let
$M
=\max_{0 \le x \le 1} |f(x)|
$.

$\begin{array}\\
|K_n(c)|
&=|\int_c^n\frac{f(\frac{x}{n})}{1+x^2}dx|\\
&\le|\int_c^n\frac{M}{1+x^2}dx|\\
&=M\int_c^n\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx\\
&=M\arctan(x)|_{x=c}^n\\
&=M(\arctan(n)-\arctan(c))\\
&=M\arctan(\frac{n-c}{1+nc})\\
&\le M(\frac{n-c}{1+nc})\\
&\le M(\frac{n-n^a}{1+n^{1+a}})
\qquad\text{if } c = n^a, 0 < a < 1\\
&\le M(\frac{n}{n^{1+a}})\\
&= M(\frac{1}{n^a})\\
\end{array}
$

So we can make
$K_n(c)
$
small by making
$c$ of order $n^a$.

For
$J_n(c)$,
since $f$ is continuous,
$|f(z)-f(0)|
\to 0
$
as $z \to 0$.
In particular,
$\max(|f(z)-f(0)|)
\to 0
$
for $0 < z < \frac1{n^a}$
so,
if
$g(n, a)
=\max(|f(z)-f(0)|)|_{x=0}^{\frac1{n^a}}
$
then,
for any $0 < \epsilon < 1,0 < a < 1$,
$g(n, a) < \epsilon
$
for large enough $n$.

Therefore,
for any $\epsilon > 0, 0 < a < 1$
for large enough $n$,

$\begin{array}\\
|J_n(c)-\int_0^{c}\frac{f(0)}{1+x^2}dx|
&\le\int_0^{c}\frac{|f(\frac{x}{n})-f(0)|}{1+x^2}dx\\
&\le\int_0^{c}\frac{\epsilon}{1+x^2}dx\\
&\le  \frac{\epsilon\pi}{2}\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$